# What is the relation between gazebo and ignition library?

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I know that my question sounds very generic.

I'm new to gazebo and I'm using version 7.8.

I have worked with some examples that use the transport layer to advertise a topic and publish Vector3 msg from the math library using Gazebo (only).

Can I use instead Vector3 or the transport from ignition library and everything work as before?
Is this still true if I want to use it with ROS?

Hope that made clear what I ask. Ignition library looks very nice by the way :)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16565/what-is-the-relation-between-gazebo-and-ignition-library?/) by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

gazebo 7.x uses gazebo topics instead of ign-transport topics. There is plan to replace the gazebo transport layer with ign-transport sometime in the future. If you're using gazebo through ROS, you can just publish to the [ROS topics](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo#gazebo.2BAC8-fuerte.ROS_API_Plugin) provided by gazebo_ros_pkgs.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on 2017-07-04**:
So, as far as I can understand,  gradually some areas will move to ignition such as transport, math. (yes. I already use math from ignition)

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-07-05**:
Correct. This tutorial gives some more context: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_dependencies_from_source&cat=install

**Comment by [Angelos](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3366/angelos/) on 2017-07-05**:
Very nice Louise, always to the point :)